# Heroku Downgrade PHP Version

Tags: php, heroku

I set up my app on Heroku PHP 7.2 as requirement:

```
{
    "name": ".../...",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.2"
    }
}
```

Now, I downgraded to 7.1 and adjusted my composer.json and composer.lock:

```
{
    "name": ".../...",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.1"
    }
}
```

But it does not work:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.        
remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> PHP app detected        
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...        
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...        
remote:        - php (7.2.10)        
remote:        - ext-gd (bundled with php)
```

I played around with different version constraints, it does not help. Additionally, I added the config option to restrict the version.

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.1.21"
    }
}
```

Does not help either.

**UPDATE**:

- I thought maybe multiple buildpacks are the problem so I set up an app with only `heroku/php` as buildpack.
- I used `^7.1` notation instead of `~7.1`
- Both Heroku-16 and -18 seem to be affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `~7.1.0`, not `~7.1`. Those are not the same. This is documented extensively in the Composer [*Versions and constraints* documentation article](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators):

> The `~` operator is best explained by example: `~1.2` is equivalent to `>=1.2 <2.0.0`, while `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0`.